# how to concatenate a message

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

I am submitting a form which first enteres the data into db and then composes a message coming from the form fields. I want the functionality that if a user resubmits the form (2 or 3 times), there should be three messages composed in the same variable?

below is how i am creating my message variable

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['save'])){
$mesg = "<strong>Logging Off at </strong> " . date("d F Y h:i:s A");
$mesg .= "<BR><BR>";
$mesg .= "<strong>Project</strong>: " . $prj_name;
$mesg .= "<BR>";
$mesg .= "<strong>Deliverable</strong>: ". $dlvrbl_name;


$mesg .= "<BR>";
$mesg .= "<strong>Time spent</strong>: " . $time_spent;
$mesg .= "<BR>";
$mesg .= "<strong>Percentage</strong>: " . $percent . "%";
$mesg .= "<BR>";
$mesg .= "<strong>Comments</strong>: " . $comments;
$mesg .= "<BR><BR>";
$mesg .= "Regards,<BR>".$employee;
}
```

its working fine for the 1 time form submission, but what if i need 2 or 3 messages in the same variable?
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 2 or 3 messages in the same variable

Comment: i mean if one message is composed and then user re-submits the form, there should be 2 messages. hope i have cleared my point

Comment: it would be better to see your full code

Comment: see my edit, just added an `if() ` to check if form is submitted

Comment: what do you mean by re-submit? perhaps you want to store it in the session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [session variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php), for example `$_SESSION['log']`:

```
session_start();

// ... 

if (isset($_REQUEST['save'])) {
    $message = isset($_SESSION['log']) ? $_SESSION['log'] . '<br>' : '';
    $message .= "<strong>Logging Off at </strong> " . date("d F Y h:i:s A");
    // ...
    $_SESSION['log'] = $message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an array using a counter?

```
$i = 0;
$mesg[$i] = "<strong>Logging Off at </strong> " . date("d F Y h:i:s A");
$mesg[$i] .= "<BR><BR>";
$mesg[$i] .= ...
```

Then for the next message:

```
$i++;
$mesg[$i] = "<strong>Logging Off at </strong> " . date("d F Y h:i:s A");
$mesg[$i] .= "<BR><BR>";
$mesg[$i] .= ...
```

When you're done, you can use `implode` or manipulate it how you would like.

Also, I would recommend you use `<br />` instead of `<br>`, and depending on the application, all you may need is a new line `\n`.

Comment: and what in the case if i don't know that how many times a form will be submitted? I mean for unlimited messages, do I have to give index numbers?

Comment: @baig772 You can use a simple counter starting with `$i = 0;`, then when a new message comes increment (`$i++`) before adding the values. See my edit.

Comment: valiue for the `$i` remains same every time i submit the form :(